# Copy log files to S3 and shutdown AutoScale instance through user-data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have an AutoScale group, that is launched when a CloudWatch alarm goes off, when there's a message in a SQS queue.

But I don't want to create another CloudWatch alarm that decreases the number of Instances in the AutoScale group because the task being made in that Instance might take longer than the Alarm settings.

So the way I tried to do was, once the Instance is created, the user-data that I passed as ".sh" file, runs the task I want, waits until it finishes, copies the file to S3 and terminates the instance.

Unfortunately, the file does get into S3 but it's empty and the instance never shuts down.

I've read this is possible to do with something like lifecycle-hooks but I wanted to know if it's possible to do the way explained above.

My user data is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
runuser -l ec2-user -c "cd /my-directory && nohup execute-my-task --trace > /logs-directory/my-log-file.log & "
PID=$!
wait $PID

runuser -l ec2-user -c "aws s3 cp /logs-directory/my-log-file.log s3://-my-logs-bucket/my-log-file.log"
PID2=$!
wait $PID2

runuser -l ec2-user -c "shutdown -h now"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

I ended up joining the commands into one while adding `&&` between commands and to shut the instance down I used:

```
aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids `wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`
```

Mind the backticks to run the `wget` command and return the instance-id.